# How to remove a marker from specific map in case of multiple maps on single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, maps, markers

Right now i have a marker drawn on two maps, but when i call  setMap(null); it removes maker from both maps.

```
function deleteAllMarkers() {
//marker = markers.filter(function (m) { return m.tag == tID; });
logStep("MARKER: In Delete");
for (let i = markers.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    logStep("MARKER: Deleted: ID: " + markers[i].ID);
    markers[i].gMarker.setMap(null);
    markers.splice(i, 1);
}
logStep("MARKER: Deleted");}
```

where single marker is saved in another variable "singleVehicle = singleMarker"

Comment: Should we presume you are using leaflet?

Comment: Yes, this how the Google Maps JS API works. You can re-add the markers to the other map if you need to, but there is no way to remove them from a single map instance.

Answer (score -1):

Just make a copy of that marker and change the name gMarker to gMarkerSingle for second map. it wouldn't delete that marker by above code